# How to ignore it AVS mismatch in authorize.net payment gateway?

Tags: php, asp.net, node.js

i want to ignore it "The transaction has been declined because of an AVS mismatch. The address provided does not match billing address of cardholder." that type of error in authorize.net payment gateway .

Comment: Please take some time to read the [help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and
["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).
Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: sure sir , but that time i haven't answer about my question . that is really need for me answer. but after some i got answer that time feel it my side to post it answer . because another person to do not waste time . that reason i post it my answer.

Comment: So you did some research and found the answer for yourself. Tremendous! Well done :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some steps, using that setps to ignoe it that avs match issue in  authorize.net payment gateway .

```
Steps : 
1. Login to authorize.net payment gateway website
2. Click on Account.
3. Click on Address Verification Service under the Security Settings section.
4. Under General AVS Responses, make sure that the last three (3) options: G, U & S are set to Allow.
5. to save settings.
```